# Convert each cell of column to list using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to convert each cell of dataframe to list

```
import pandas as pd
a=[619, 200, 50, 45]
dic={"a":a}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)

#Output should be like this:
  a
[619]
[200]
[50]
[45]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
df["a"] = df["a"].apply(lambda x: [x])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
       a
0  [619]
1  [200]
2   [50]
3   [45]
```

Or:

```
df["a"] = [[x] for x in df["a"]]
```